# Get tenant displayName using Kusto queries

Tags: kql, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I can't seem to find a way to retrieve the displayName for a tenantid using a table available in Azure Monitor.

Using Azure Resource Graph Kusto queries I query resources across tenants (Lighthouse).
The resources contains a property for tenantId, but I want a way to lookup that tenantId to a name.

E.g. in the column tenantId I want that mapped up to the displayName.

```
Resources
| where type == "microsoft.network/virtualnetworks"
| project tenantId, id, name
```

Is there a way or do I end up getting that information from another place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there is any Tenant table in ARG like `resourcecontainers` has subscription names.

It looks like there are CLI extras that will do the extra lookups/mappings for you, not sure why that isn't a feature of the queries themselves?

in workbooks, you could possibly call the ARM api to look up tenants:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list?view=rest-resources-2022-12-01&tabs=HTTP

and then use a workbooks Merge datasource to join in the names?

Answer (score 0):

I'll add the solution I went for based on John Gardner's answer.

**Step 1: Create a hidden text parameter**
[image: Text parameter]

**Step 2: Parse text content**

Create a new Query Item and create a variable to hold the tenant information.

```
let tenantLookup = (print packed = (parse_json('{hiddenTenantLookup:value}'))
| mv-expand packed.value
| evaluate bag_unpack(packed_value)
| project defaultDomain, displayName, domains, id, tenantId
);
//tenantLookup
```

**Step 2: Join tenantLookup with another table**

```
| join kind = inner tenantLookup on $left.tenantId == $right.tenantId
```

**EDIT: (Improving based on comment feedback from John Gardner)**

I'm creating a query step and use the `Make the step conditional visible` with a parameter, which is just empty, to hide the step.

I'm unable to use odata notation `$select` with azure resource manager, so I get the all the fields. But I can limit the projected columns using the jsonpath.

```
// Doesn't work with $select
/tenants?$select=tenantId,displayName&api-version=2022-12-01

// Works without $select
/tenants?api-version=2022-12-01
```

[image: tenant list query step]

Then I do a `Left outer join` on the two tables:
[image: Merge tables]

Comment: (in this specific case the way you did it that whole response from the tenant api could be *huge* depending on what tenants someone has access to, which then is being sent as part of the logs query.  if it is a LOT, i'd suggest not hiding it in a param, but making a hidden query step that projects *just* the id and display name fields, and then use query step that uses merge to merge the 2 queries.  or alternatively, if the tenants api supports $select or any other ODATA operators you could trim that WAY down in what gets returned in the hidden parameter?)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was unable to use the $select odata operator, but using a query step  and limit the projected columns, then merging the tables works.